# How to fetch the first matching element from the array

Tags: javascript

I have got a array of Markers

```
var markers = [{
    "longititude": "78.377670",
    "latitude": "17.439669",
    "name": "one"
}, {
    "longititude": "78.377617",
    "latitude": "17.439692",
    "name": "two"
}, {
    "longititude": "78.377644",
    "latitude": "17.439674",
    "name": "three"
}, {
    "longititude": "78.377665",
    "latitude": "17.439667",
    "name": "four"
}]
```

I  am sending latitude and longitude and checking if it falls under a range of certain distance .

In response from the function i am expecting the total count and the latitude and longitude values under which it falls .

But i am always getting the last element of the array

http://jsfiddle.net/1nm9adn3/1/

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue .

Comment: It's better to post your Javascript function directly in your question.

Comment: In simple i need the first value , but where as now i am getting the last value

Comment: Look this version of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1nm9adn3/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var markers = [
{
    "longititude": "78.377665",
    "latitude": "17.439669",
    "name": "one"
},
{
    "longititude": "78.377617",
    "latitude": "17.439692",
    "name": "two"
},
{
    "longititude": "78.377644",
    "latitude": "17.439674",
    "name": "three"
},
{
    "longititude": "78.377665",
    "latitude": "17.439667",
   "name": "four"
 }
]

 function fetchValue(markers, lat, lng) {
 var count = 0;
 var latitude = [];
 var longitude =[];
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     var latit = markers[i].latitude;
   var longit = markers[i].longititude;
    if (lat == latit && lng == longit) {
        count++;
        latitude.push(latit);
        longitude.push(longit);            
    }
    else if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((lat - latitude), 2) + Math.pow((lng - longitude), 2)) < 0.000005) {
        count++;
    }
}
var result = {    
    count: count,
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude
};
return result;
 }
 var resltval = fetchValue(markers,17.439669,78.377665);
 alert(JSON.stringify(resltval));
```

Answer (score 1):

You replace the value of latitude and longitude in your function every time. So by the time the loop ends, `var latitude` and `var longitude` will always have the values of the last element in your array. You should save the value of `i` when your if clause detects the correct marker and then return `markers[i].latitude`.

Comment: i am unable to achieve that , could you please let me know how to do this

Answer (score 1):

did you mean something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/1nm9adn3/4/

```
function fetchValue(markers, lat, lng) {
    var result = {    
        count: 0,
        values: []
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latitude = markers[i].latitude;
        var longitude = markers[i].longititude;
        if (lat == latitude && lng == longitude) {
            result.count++;
            result.values.push({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});
        }
        else if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((lat - latitude), 2) + Math.pow((lng - longitude), 2)) < 0.000005) {
            result.count++;
            result.values.push({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about why you want to respond with the first matching element, instead of the nearest element, but this would do the trick anyway:

```
function fetchValue(markers, lat, lng) {
var count = 0;
var firstMatchingLatitude = null;
var firstMatchingLongititude = null;
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var latitude = markers[i].latitude;
    var longitude = markers[i].longititude;
    if (lat == latitude && lng == longitude) {
        if(firstMatchingLatitude == null){
            firstMatchingLatitude = latitude;
            firstMatchingLongititude = longitude;
        }
        count++;
    }
    else if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((lat - latitude), 2) + Math.pow((lng - longitude), 2)) < 0.000005) {
        if(firstMatchingLatitude == null){
            firstMatchingLatitude = latitude;
            firstMatchingLongititude = longitude;
        }
        count++;
    }
}
var result = {    
    count: count,
    latitude: firstMatchingLatitude,
    longitude: firstMatchingLongititude
};
return result;
}
```

The trick is that you were setting latitude and longititude in every repetition of the for loop. Oh, and it's "latitude" instead of "latititude" ;)

Good luck with that!!